# displaying the folder list using list datatype java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need to display a static folder hierarchy  in java. I already have a folder class defined and have to use the same. No use of `File` class is allowed! Class folder is:

```
class Folder
{
    boolean isFile;
    String folderName;
    List<Folder> subFolders;
}
```

The code i am trying to use is :

```
class LisF
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Folder a=new Folder("C:/hello");
        Folder b=new Folder("C:/one");
        Folder c=new Folder("C:/two");
        a.subFolders.add(b);
        b.subFolders.add(c);
        Iterator itr = a.subFolders.iterator();
        Iterator itr1= b.subFolders.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object element = itr.next();
            //System.out.print("The list is "+(Folder)element.putFName());
            System.out.println("The lis is "+element);
        }

    }

}
```

It runs and gives the output as Folder@1234 which no doubt gives the name of the object. But i need the name of the string passed i.e to display the subfolders of hello it should display one and subFolders of one should display two! But instead i am getting the object names!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the `toString` method in the classes you want/need to print the objects as `String`s. In this case, you need to implement it in the `Folder` class:

```
class Folder {

    //class definition...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //implementation sample
        return this.folderName;
    }
}
```

Comment: reached end of file while parsing!!

Comment: That looks like another problem/bug in your code and is off-topic for the question.

Comment: it was running before toString!! :|

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added anything else? If so, please update your code in your question to provide the right guidance in this problem. By the way, I've tested your code in my Eclipse IDE and it runs fine.